# Changing HTML id to class messes up CSS styling

Tags: html, css, class, identifier

I am wanting to change some items that I have labeled using ids to one single class so that in my CSS I can refer to them with `.sortsubmenu` rather than `#sortsongmenu`, `#sortartistmenu`, etc.

The problem is that when I change one of them from an id to a class, it messes up the formatting. In the picture below, everything about the songsubmenu and artistsubmenu are exactly the same, only songsubmenu is identified using an id and artistsubmenu is identified using a class.

[image]

```css
#topbar {
 background-color: #222;
}

#topbar_wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: left;
}

#mainmenu {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 position: relative;
 min-width: 200px;
}

#mainmenu li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
}

#mainmenu li:hover {
 background-color: #333;
}

#mainmenu li a {
 color: #CCC;
 display: block;
 padding: 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#mainmenu li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}

#sortmenu {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #333;
 border: 5px solid #222;
 border-top: 0;
 margin-left: -5px;
}

#sortmenu > li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}

#sortmenu li a:hover {
 color: #699;
}

#sortmenu li:hover ul {
 display: inline-block;
}

#sortsongmenu, .sortsubmenu {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #333;
 border: 5px solid #222;
 border-left: 0px;
 text-align: right;
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 width: 100px;
}

#sortsongmenu li, .sortsubmenu li {
 display: inline;
}

#sortsongmenu li a:hover, .sortsubmenu li a:hover {
 color: #DB7093;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <div id="topbar_wrapper">
    <ul id="mainmenu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Search</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sort By &#9660</a>
        <ul id="sortmenu">
          <li><a href='#'>Song</a>
            <ul id="sortsongmenu">
              <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>Z to A</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Artist</a>
            <ul class="sortsubmenu">
              <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>Z to A</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Album</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Genre</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>BPM</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Release Date</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Add Song</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#mainmenu li` rule is getting in your way. It's not overridden by the class-based selector, as it was by the id-based selector.

Keep that positioning / size to the *immediate* descendants only, that is, change:

```
#mainmenu li {
```

to

```
#mainmenu > li {
```

and all is well.

```css
#topbar {

  background-color: #222;

}

#topbar_wrapper {

  width: 100%;

  margin: 0 auto;

  text-align: left;

}

#mainmenu {

  list-style-type: none;

  padding: 0px;

  margin: 0px;

  position: relative;

  min-width: 200px;

}

#mainmenu > li {

  display: inline-block;

  width: 200px;

}

#mainmenu li:hover {

  background-color: #333;

}

#mainmenu li a {

  color: #CCC;

  display: block;

  padding: 15px;

  text-decoration: none;

}

#mainmenu li:hover > ul {

  display: block;

}

#sortmenu {

  display: none;

  position: absolute;

  background-color: #333;

  border: 5px solid #222;

  border-top: 0;

  margin-left: -5px;

}

#sortmenu > li {

  display: block;

  position: relative;

}

#sortmenu li a:hover {

  color: #699;

}

#sortmenu li:hover ul {

  display: inline-block;

}

#sortsongmenu,

.sortsubmenu {

  display: none;

  position: absolute;

  background-color: #333;

  border: 5px solid #222;

  border-left: 0px;

  text-align: right;

  top: 0;

  left: 100%;

  width: 100px;

}

#sortsongmenu li,

.sortsubmenu li {

  display: inline;

}

#sortsongmenu li a:hover,

.sortsubmenu li a:hover {

  color: #DB7093;

}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <div id="topbar_wrapper">
    <ul id="mainmenu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Search</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sort By &#9660</a>
        <ul id="sortmenu">
          <li><a href='#'>Song</a>
            <ul id="sortsongmenu">
              <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>Z to A</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Artist</a>
            <ul class="sortsubmenu">
              <li><a href='#'>A to Z</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#'>Z to A</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Album</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Genre</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>BPM</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#'>Release Date</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Add Song</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Kenney Were you aware that the code snippet embedded in the answer is *already* a working example? (serious question, not everyone knows how they work, or that they work)

Comment: eh, no... I didn't notice that.. Thanks!  (Actually my fiddle and your answer were created in parallel; only saw your answer when I was done...)

Comment: thank you, that seemed to fix the problem. I think I need to pay attention to targeting only immediate descendants in the future, as this isn't the first issue ive had due to my neglect of using them. Just a tip for any other css beginners.